# Does Alibaba Cloud Function support Node.js with Express?

Tags: node.js, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs, alibaba-cloud-function-compute

For AWS Lambda there are some solutions which get Express to work with their serverless functions (for example the node package "server-http"). I can not find any solution to get my Express node function in the Alibaba Cloud Function working. Did someone try it with Alibaba Cloud Function and can show me a simple example? Thank you.

Comment: Please add to your question the code you've tried that isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is function in Alibaba like AWS having Lambda for server less computing it is know as

> `"Aliyun Function Compute Server less"`

what i would suggest to use server less framework so you can easily deploy it to Alibaba.

Cli of alibaba is also same the aws cli you have to add the secrets key and access key to configure the cli.

```
aliyun_access_key_id = ""
aliyun_access_key_secret = ""
aliyun_account_id = ""
```

so in your case if you know server less framework node and express you can at Alibaba check here :

> https://github.com/aliyun/serverless-aliyun-function-compute

Comment: I have found it, too but there is no example for a case with Express. I think it is not usable for a Express case. The AWS solutions doing something like that (serverless-http). They place app in the serverless function and return it as module.exports.handler:

`
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);`
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

There are SDKs for different programming languages and / or environments and NodeJS is also one of the SDKs for Alibaba Cloud Function Compute service.

NodeJS' SDK from the official documentation can be found here on Github
https://github.com/aliyun/fc-nodejs-sdk?spm=a2c63.p38356.a3.2.16951455T7nLyG

This should help you in using Function Compute in conjunction to NodeJS and Express Framework.